# What's the most popular (easy and efficient) way of building a multilingual site in Wordpress (no need for multilingual posts)

Tags: wordpress, multilingual

I would like to build a multilingual site with Wordpress. Everything should be multilingual except the posts. Should I go for Gettext or does Wordpress have a "native" way of doing this?

(I would also need a language switcher)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched for that feature for month without success. The only way to do it was not acceptable.

**Enabling the "network" feature (multi-blog), and create a sub-blog for each language.**

www.example.org/en

www.example.org/fr

etc.

There are some [plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress) that may help, but none met my requirements:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress